# How to hard delete an orphan commit in git?

Tags: git

I have local commit that are not on any branch that I would like to delete.
I don't want to rebase them, I really want to delete them, and loose all the content related to these commit.

Is their a command to do so ?

So far I've tried interactive rebase as many suggested, but it just move commit around, it doesn't delete them. I've also tried to use reflog delete, but I can't figure out how to pass a specific commit Id to the command.

Here's the working tree:

```
o [master] Commit #6  
|  
o Commit #5  
|  
| o Commit #4  
|/  
o Commit #3  
|  
o Commit #2  
|  
o Commit #1
```

I want to physically delete the commit #4.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "move commit around"?

Comment: @greg0ire well, the commit still exist, but is linked to something else.. That's what a rebase do: changing the commit parent... no ?

Comment: In the interactive rebase, you need to completely delete the line with the commit you want to delete.  Reverting the commit is simply creating a new commit applying the reverse diff of the one specified.  This just adds another commit you'll have to delete.  Try the rebase and completely remove the line.

Comment: @Brian Riehman, hum. Do you have specific commands to do what your telling me (really physically delete a commit) ? Consider that I only have a commitId...

Comment: When you run the interactive rebase and it opens your text editor, simply remove the commit line that you want removed.  git will reapply all the other commits and that one will no longer be reachable by the current branch.  The commit will then be culled by git's garbage collection after a month.

Comment: Running sudo git rebase -i origin/master, I can't find the commit #4. running sudo git rebase -i cb497092 (the commitId #4), I only see the commit #5 and 6. I'm lost.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem as asked here (which is why I found this question) but it turns out to be a problem with gitk to properly refresh itself after a rebase. Restarting the application "solves" the issue.

Comment: Just FYI, I realize this is an old question, and the current answer is good, but there is a new answer from TamaMcGlinn that is even better.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If the commit is not referenced by anything, it will be removed with git's garbage collection, in time.

If you want to force it before hand, use `git gc --prune=now --aggressive`

Comment: Well I was on a branch, then I've made a commit, then I reverted the commit with a GUI ( I think this correspond to a hard reset ). So now my commit is out of all branch, but the commit is still "parent" to a branch. I've tried the command, but I still have my useless commits :(

Comment: Reverting the commit in git is not just taking the commit away.  It actually applies the reverse of the commit.  If the commit you don't want is at the tip of a branch, use `git reset --hard shaOfLastGoodCommit`.  That will remove the bad commit(s) and move the tip of your branch to the last good commit.

Comment: I already did a reset --hard, twice... it only changed the branch head (the "master tag") to the commit I wanted to delete, then I replaced it on the real branch head, but the commit I want to delete is still there.

Comment: According to your graph, something(tag, branch, another commit...) must be pointing to commit #4 for it to still be visible. what does `git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline` show?  Are any decorators on the same line as that commit? Are any commits above it?

Comment: The git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline return the commit #1,2,3,5,6 The commitId of the commit #4 is not displayed.

Comment: So where are you seeing the commit?

Comment: ho wait, I think I had a display problem, I've re-ran the command and I see the commit #4 now, it's displayed like: | * cb49709 (HEAD) lorem ipsum. the commit tree is the same as I've drawed in my original post.

Comment: That means that your HEAD is still pointed to it.  Checkout a different branch and the commit should disappear. After that, garbage collection will take care of it.

Comment: Ah yup, you're right, now that I've "re-checkedout" the master (commit #6), I no longer see the commit with your specific git log command. Hovewer git gc --prune=now --aggressive didn't physically removed the commits. Do I absolutly need to wait a month ?

Comment: Does `git fsck` display the commit? Why do you think it is not removed?

Comment: git fsck display nothing (same as if I hit enter without entering any command). I think it's not removed because I use SmartGit, and I'm able to find the commit if I do Query->Load all commits in the log windows.

Comment: Hmm, never used it, so not sure where it's getting that info from.  Does `git show <commitSha>' pull up the commit?

Comment: Yup, since the beginning I've always considered that the GUI could be unreliable and display me some sort of cache... but it appear to be a pretty nice piece of software ;) So yeah, I can still view the commit using the commitID, that's why I'm keep saying it's not physically deleted yet... :(

Comment: It's probably still in the reflog for HEAD, since you had it checked out recently, which means git can't GC it. There's no real reason to be so desperate to remove all copies of a commit, since it's not reachable from any branches, but if you were desperate you could mess with the reflogs. See `git help reflog`.

Comment: @amalloy Cool, didn't know that the reflog would keep it from being orphaned as well.

Answer (score 7):

To fully delete a commit, you need to delete all references to it, and then force an aggressive garbage-collection.

If you still have branches pointing to the commit, delete those first.

Next you will need to flush the commit from the reflog, which keeps references to every commit you have visited in the past 90 days by default (replace [commit-hash] with  the first 8 characters of the commit hash):

```
git reflog --all | grep [commit-hash] | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d':' -f1 | tac | xargs git reflog delete
```

(I used `tac` to reverse the order of deletions because if the commit shows up multiple times in the reflog, deleting an entry shifts all the entries following it)

Finally, force the garbage collection:

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

After this, `git show [commit-hash]` will no longer show the commit, so you will know it is really deleted.

Comment: The `git reflog` command needs to have the --all flag, otherwise it will only show the reflog of HEAD but not of each individual branch, which git also stores: git reflog  --all | grep [commit-hash] | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d':' -f1 | tac | xargs git reflog delete

Answer (score 3):

To remove a commit, you just need to make sure that it's no longer part of any branch. That is, for each branch in your repository, make sure the bad commit is not part of the child-to-parent chain of commits defining that branch. If you do find such a branch, either delete it, or change its history so that it no longer includes the bad commit.

Once that's true, the bad commit will be garbage-collected eventually.

Comment: Only on a system which automatically garbage collects.