# Force remove all commits ahead of HEAD?

Tags: git

I made a mess in my git repo earlier, doing merges and adding tags and the like. I've now reset my develop branch to the commit I want (the one in bold), but there's still a mess of commits in the history ahead of that commit:

[image]

How do I get rid of those commits (starting at where the branches first diverge at 487ff69) as if they never happened? This doesn't necessarily need to happen in SourceTree - terminal commands are fine as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you pushed any of these (messy) commits to a public repository?

Comment: If those commits are not referenced from anywhere else, they should get removed by git's garbage collection. (You may need to remove the tags though.) See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7907518/245915

Answer (score 2):

Git tries quite hard never to *remove* commits (with a few exceptions that we can ignore here).  What I think you want here is to make these commits *unreachable*, and that's quite a bit easier, because references—mostly branch and tag names (things like git's "stash" are also references but again we can ignore that here)—are what make commits reachable.

Thus, to make the commits not-reachable, we simply move or delete the references.

Your `develop` is already moved: it now points to the bolded commit, just as you wanted.  Presumably you did a `git reset` or GUI-equivalent to achieve that.  The unwanted commits are now referenced only<sup>1</sup> through the tags you added, `0.1.3`, `0.1.2`, and `0.1.1`.

Thus, all you need to do is delete the tags (or stop using them), and the commits will (seem to) disappear.  (They will still stick around for a while, 30 to 90 days by default depending on other details, but if there are no "named" references they'll go away after that point; see also the footnote here.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There's a sort of side reference to these commits, or more than one really, through git's "reflog".  Whenever git updates a reference, such as a branch name like `develop` or even the indirect "current head of tree" reference named `HEAD`, it updates the reflog for that reference (if the reflog exists).  These reflog entries are what protect commits: each entry has a time stamp and a raw SHA-1 value, and these act as references to retain commits (or tags, if they point to annotated tags).  Any reference to a commit will retain it, and then if it has its own references to parent commit(s), that commit will retain its parent(s), and so on.  This is what makes git so Borg-like in its insistence on keeping anything ever stored in the repository.